# Angular 2 / 4 change env variable after build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I read that you can put your environement variable in environement.ts / environement.prod.ts . 
ok

But this file are compile so I can't change it after the build. 
Is the anyway to do that ?

(I am using angular-cli)

Thanks

Comment: The point of an "environment" is to create different builds easily. The only way to access files _after_ build is to add them to an assets folder or access them externally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yup, just like this :

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    env: 'Dev'
};
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    env: 'Prod'
};
```

**EDIT** What I did to solve that issue is using the window object like so :

```
export const environment = {
    env: window['env'] || 'Dev' // you get it for prod
};
```

And in the index.html added this :

```
<script src="./config.js"></script>
```

And in the config.js file, the "system guy" can put this :

```
window['env'] = 'New environment';
```

This way, if no config file is provided, the env variable will have a value, and if the config file is provided, it will take the value from it.

Comment: Well, they're supposed to be environment variables, meaning you can't change them ... If you want variables to change, you can store them in the window object, or the localStorage

Comment: environment variable don't change... but I don't know them... I give the app to the system guy and he will put them... that's why

Comment: okay thanks ! 
one more question : Can I make distinct var with that solution ?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by that, but if you want to add variables, surr, just call it like this `myVar: window['anyNameYouWant'] || 'default value'`

Answer (score 7):

We can find all `environment` variable in `var environment = {}` object in *main.bundle.js* file.

NOTE: Restart server after changes.

Comment: i think it's not perfect solution, to open, find and replace at main.bundle.js every time we want to made a change

Answer (score 4):

After the build, we can find main.bundle script file, you will find and change the environment variables.

in main.bundle.js file :

```
var environment = {
  production: false,
  serviceUrl: "<<URl>>",
  prodService: "environment"
};
```

Comment: easy way to do it, better to take backup of main-es5 *********** files before making changes

Answer (score 0):

```
(function (window) {
 window['env'] = window['env'] || {};
 // Environment variables
 window['env']['apiUrl'] = 'your-api-url';
})(this);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**